# Is there a tool that can inspect varchar data and suggest suitable datatypes?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

It's quite a common practice to import external data into a staging table using large varchar or nvarchar fields either to allow more control of data validation and conversion downstream.

When creating a new ETL, one has, therefore, to create destination tables of the correct data types.

I'm certain there must be a tool that can analyse the data inside (n)varchar columns and suggest suitable destination column datatypes, in a very similar way to the Import Data Wizard does for flat file data sources.

I've always done it manually but it becomes quite tedious when creating ETLs for 100+ column tables. There must be a tool to get me 90% of the way there automatically.

Comment: One alternative is to export the data as CSV and use the import wizard to suggest datatypes. That seems a bit long winded but might well be quicker than doing it all by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume 2012+ AND you have a table that looks like this.

```
Col1        Col2            Col3
2018-05-23  Another Value   25.26
2018-06-30  John Smith      3635.556365
2018-07-01  Jane Doe        NULL
```

Then we can have a little XML fun.  Cross Apply B will convert the row into XML while Cross Apply C will "dynamically" unpivot your data.  Then it is a simple aggregation.

```
;with cte as (
Select C.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select ColNr  = Row_Number() over (Order by (select null))
                      ,Item   = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value  = a.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
             ) C
)
Select ColNr       = max(ColNr)
      ,Item 
      ,CntValues   = sum(1) 
      ,MinStrLen   = min(len(Value))
      ,MaxStrLen   = max(len(Value))
      ,MinValue    = min(Value)
      ,MaxValue    = max(Value)
      ,PctNumeric  = sum(IIF(try_convert(money,Value) is null,0,1)) / sum(convert(money,1))
      ,MinNumeric  = min(try_convert(money,Value))
      ,MaxNumeric  = max(try_convert(money,Value))
      ,MaxDecimal  = max(case when try_convert(money,Value) is not null and charindex('.',Value)>0 then len(parsename(Value,1)) else 0 end)
      ,PctDate     = sum(IIF(try_convert(date,Value) is null,0,1)) / sum(convert(money,1))
      ,MinDateTime = min(try_convert(datetime,Value))
      ,MaxDateTime = max(try_convert(datetime,Value))
 From  cte
 Group By Item
 Order By 1
```

**Returns**

[image]

**Please Note:** This is not a complete answer, nor does int make a suggestion, but it will add a little insight into generic table.

Comment: Oh now that's quite a lot neater than what I was thinking about coming up with. Thanks.

Comment: With a bit of tweaking that seems to to do what I wanted, so thank you.

I'm still convinced that there's an obvious tool somewhere in SSIS that is right under my nose but your code solved my immediate problem. 

I can use that output to generate the destination table spec and the data conversion script.

Comment: @RichardPolhill Happy to help

Comment: I like this a lot! Any way to count max decimal places to suggest decimal(18,x)

Comment: @KeithL Give me a moment to noodle it

Comment: @KeithL Perhaps something like this        ,MaxDecimal  = max(case when try_convert(money,Value) is not null then len(parsename(Value,1)) else 0 end)

Comment: @KeithL Updated the answer to include MaxDecimal

Comment: @KeithL Made a little change to trap INT  ,MaxDecimal  = max(case when try_convert(money,Value) is not null and charindex('.',Value)>0 then len(parsename(Value,1)) else 0 end)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Did you invent SQL? You do things with it that are impressive/extraordinary.

Comment: @JWeezy Thanks for the grin  :)

Answer (score 1):

I know the problem is solved and @John is great.

I wanted to share my idea in such interesting question.

In such problem ,script has to cover many Test cases and it has tested thoroughly.

My script is tested once or two for small example.

If it suit the requirement then it can be developed to full robust script.

```
--create table ETL(Col1 varchar(50), Col2 varchar(50), Col3 varchar(50))
--insert into ETL values
-- ('2018-05-23','Another Value','25.26')
--,('2018-06-30','John Smith','3635.50')
--,('2018-07-01','Jane Doe', '')
--select * from ETL
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(50) = 'ETL'
    ,@colName VARCHAR(300)
    ,@Sql NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @DataType VARCHAR(50) = ''

DECLARE @getobject CURSOR CREATE TABLE #temp (
    ColName VARCHAR(50)
    ,colType VARCHAR(50)
    ) SET @getobject = CURSOR
FOR
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

OPEN @getobject

FETCH NEXT
FROM @getobject
INTO @colName

--Even if one data is decimal then data type has to be decimal
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE #temp

    SET @DataType = ''
    -- it is necessary to make column null if it is blank(you can do this in ETL too)
    SET @Sql = 'update ' + @TableName + '  set ' + @colName + '=null where ' + @colName + '='''''

    EXEC (@Sql)

    SET @Sql = ''
    SET @Sql = '  if not exists(select 1 from ' + @TableName + ' where ISNUMERIC(' + @colName + ')=0 and (' + @colName + ' is not null ))
begin

if exists(select  ' + @colName + ' from dbo.ETL where TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,5),' + @colName + '  ) is not null)
insert into #temp values(''' + @colName + ''',''DECIMAL(18,5)'')

ELSE
insert into #temp values(''' + @colName + ''',''INT'')

end
else if not exists(select 1 from dbo.ETL where ISDATE(' + @colName + ')=0 and (' + @colName + ' is not null ))
insert into #temp values(''' + @colName + ''',''DateTime'')'

    -- print @Sql
    EXEC (@Sql)

    SELECT @DataType = colType
    FROM #temp

    PRINT @DataType

    IF (
            @DataType IS NOT NULL
            AND @DataType <> ''
            )
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql = ''
        SET @Sql = 'ALTER table ' + @TableName + '
              Alter column ' + @colName + '  ' + @DataType + ''

        PRINT @Sql

        EXEC (@Sql)
    END

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getobject
    INTO @colName
END

CLOSE @getobject

DEALLOCATE @getobject

--drop table ETL
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah that's pretty similar to the way I was planning to go about it.